# How to display list items with each tag of custom post-types as data-filter and text?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

as a newbie in php I am having trouble achieving an as I guess quite simple thing.

I got this code so far (in a php template file):

```
<?php                                    
    //Define my custom post type name in the arguments                           
    $args = array('post_type' => 'reference-document');          
?> 

<ul> 
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".2013">2013</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".2014">2014</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".2015">2015</a></li>      
</ul>
```

In my custom post-type 'reference-document' I have a list of available tags with the years 2013,2014,2015

Now, actually, my above code is working but I wish to output the li list depending on how many years ever the user might enter as tags in the post-type. (so eventually also 2016,2017…)

So I guess I need to create the list with a php loop or whatever taking the available tags of my post-type as arguments. So far I have tried something like:

```
<?php                           
    $tags = get_the_tags();   
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        echo '<li><a href="#" data-filter=".'.esc_attr($tag->tag_name).'">'.esc_attr($tag->tag_name).'</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

to get the same output as I had achieved “manually”. But this throws errors and I am quite stuck here. Anyone how can give me the right code?

Please do not forward me to the official standard WP documentations as I tried to understand them but didn’t succeed. I need concrete code. Then I might understand how it is working. Thanks so much in advance!

**EDIT**
When I add the if statement in my code as:

```
<?php                           
    $tags = get_the_tags(); 
    if(!empty($tags)) {  
        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
            echo '<li><a href="#" data-filter=".'.esc_attr($tag->tag_name).'">'.esc_attr($tag->tag_name).'</a></li>';
        }
    }
?>
```

in fact there are no more errors but nothing happens also. Which I guess means the 'tags' array is empty. But why? There are tags assigned in my custom post-type. As I said I am really new here so I guess my code contains some semantic illness. Please check!

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /homepages/24/d469239235/htdocs/.../wp-content/themes/az_alice-child/template-investors-reference-docs.php on line 124

Comment: Well, that just means that your `$tags` isn't a array

Comment: In the wp doc, the example perform a if($tags) before looping through them. Maybe you don't have any tag and your tags variable is empty ?

Comment: you should always check  `if(!empty($variable))` before any loop.

Comment: This means first of all that my code is not completely idiotic? Semantically correct so far?

Comment: As a matter of fact my posts inside the 'reference-document' custom post-type HAVE tags (2013,2014) assigned. Check my edit, please.

Comment: dump the result of the get_the_tags function to see if it fetches any tag

Comment: what does dump mean here?

Comment: I wonder if I have to do any kind of referencing (with $args?) to the custom post-type before being able to get its tags.

Comment: I downvoated this question as being incomprehensible. I would delete it.

Comment: This is incomprehensible? I mean I showed clearly what I result I need to have. Oh man. Incredible. Everytime one has a question in a field which is new for him (that’s what it is for asking questions, no?) and one gets downvoted. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I succeed at least in part by doing so:

```
<ul> 
    <li><a href="#" class="has-items selected" data-filter="*">All</a></li>                         

        <?php

            //Define the loop based on arguments                            
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

            //Display the contents                            
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();          

        ?>                         

        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".<?php
            $posttags = get_the_tags();
            if ($posttags) {
                foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                    echo $tag->slug; 
                }
            }
        ?>"><?php
            $posttags = get_the_tags();
            if ($posttags) {
                foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                    echo $tag->slug; 
                }
            }
        ?></a></li>                                   

<?php endwhile;?>
```

It seems I had a lack of understanding what it means to have tags for a custom post-type since it seems they cannot be retrieved as long as not looping through the posts having them attached. I thought it was possible to say instead: Ok, here we have the XXX post-type let’s check (or output) i.g. for a isotope script, what tags exist for this “category” and display them.

The problem that my solution left is to check which tags are double and then subtract them from the array first.